# Why are telephone numbers sometimes verbally expanded?

Tags: números

I was listening to a Spanish-language radio station on my commute this morning, and in giving a phone number, the "disc jockey" said "tres veintitres" for "323". Why? "tres dos tres" is shorter. Is it just because it "sounds better" or what's the reason?

Comment: Why is this so surprising? We do it in English, too, often entirely at random.

Comment: I never do that with phone numbers (in English), and don't recall hearing any others do it, either.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon: You never hear "one eight-hundred..." in a TV/radio advertisement in English?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite usual, to group digits arbitrarly when pronouncing phone numbers. And in this case, I find it natural, I'd probably pronounce it in that way: "**tres veintitrés**" sounds to me more neat and clear than "**tres dos tres**". True, the later is shorter, but it also can be slightly more confusing (in particular, "dos" sometimes -perhaps not here- can be confused with "doce").

Answer (score 8):

Consider the case of years: "1978" for you is *nineteen seventy eight*, which for me in Chile is *mil nueve setenta y ocho* ("thousand and nine and seventy eight ").

Why none of us says *one-nine-seven-eight* (the shortest) or *one thousand nine hundred and seventy eight* (the proper)?

We need to group units into manageable pieces by both memory as phonics. *Tres-dos-tres* involves memorizing 3 units. *Tres-veintitrés* involves memorizing 2. The time loss talking is minimal compared to the memory won (one-third).

This is not a feature of the Spanish language but of cognition in general ("chunking").

Comment: I agree for phone numbers but here in Colombia we read years usually as numbers so in your example we most usually would say _mil novecientos setenta y ocho_

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with the answer accepted, although for some specific cases might be right.

First of all he is asking about a telephone number. We must remeber that each country, and even in some cases, different states, have different phone numbers convention, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_conventions_for_writing_telephone_numbers)

In the case the radio was Spanish (from Spain), our convention is to say the numbers in Madrid 91 (province prefix) XXX - XX - XX

For my home's telephone number is say, something like ninety one, one two three, zero five, twenty two. In the previous one I changed a little.

Second, a famous radio called Los Cuarenta Principales (40), play with their name and number, since their number is 91 X 39 40 40.

Answer (score 2):

Radio is an entirely auditory experience. I would suggest the purpose is primarily  to give a boring telephone in a way that sounds more interesting and much more memorable. I think it is accomplished here by changing the rhythm and emphasizing the accent on `tres`. Besides that I think the economy of saving one syllable is made up by not having the extra space between the three words (numerals) individually.